# Adding Magento's required structure to a php file

Tags: php

This is a weird request but I've done it before and it worked wonders.

I have a need to make a custom PHP file in my sites root folder. I need to give this file access to all of the magento functions inside.

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup(‘core_setup’);

I did this once before successfully when I wrote a script to parse a massive database of trading cards into useful data then has the php script automatically add the cards to the database.

My problem is I did this on a old version of XMAPP that I sadly lost the backup files of when my pc died.

What files do I need to include in a blank php file to have access to the required magento core functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
umask(0);
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

Now Magento is all fired upp and ready to go

Comment: Thanks, now I can finally play with my Module install script without having to delete the messed up versions 20 times an hour :)

Comment: Setting the store is not mandatory.

Comment: AFAIK, It's mandatory in case if you want some write operation to the database.

Comment: @MagePsycho Only mandatory for updates to the product and category entities.

Comment: @ChrisMorris this script will not trigger the update workflow. You will want to call `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()`

Answer (score 5):

I use this one in my /cron/ folder:

```
<?php

session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'en_US');
umask(0);

$compilerConfig = 'includes/config.php';
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
    include($compilerConfig);
}

$mageFilename = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../app/Mage.php';

require_once $mageFilename;

Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

// If you're going to use store view emulation:
Mage::app()->getLocale();
```