# Display Products [Ordered] of Particular Designer after login

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, products

magento site : www.1234.com

We have lot of Designers in site (Seller/ Vendor). we assigned each product to one **Designer**  with help of attribute **Designer ID** as below image under `Catalog > Manage Products` section

[image]

we are displaying all the orders in custom page : **www.1234.com/php/site6/orders.php**

if we login as **admin** we can see **all orders** in page .

if we login as **Designer1**, than we can see all orders that contains **Designer1's** Products.

if we login as **Designer2**, than we can see all orders that contains **Designer2's** Products.

[image]

Now, **Product 1** belongs to **Designer1 [kidsdial2]** , **Product 2** belongs to **Designer2 [kidsdial3]**.

if we login as Designer1 or Designer2 , we can see as above image.

It contains Products of both Designer 1 & Designer 2 as because customer ordered both products in single order.

but I want to display only Designer 1 product if we login as Designer1 & same for Designer 2

We are saving Designer id & Designer names in custom database with **table** `tbl_users` , **columns** : `userID` [Designer ID] , `name` [Designer]

```
function getDesignerCollection()
    {

    $user_home = new USER();
    require_once '../../app/Mage.php';

    Mage::app();

    $stmts = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
    $stmts->execute(array(
        ":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']
    ));
    $rows = $stmts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $accountType = $rows['type'];
    if ($accountType == "admin")
        {
        $is_admin = true;
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id', array(
            'nin' => '0'
        ));

        }
      else
        {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id', array(
            'like' => '%' . $_SESSION['userSession'] . '%'
        ));

        }

    $i = 0;

    foreach($order as $orderData)
        {
        $orderitems = $orderData['dproduct_id'];
        $orderitemsarray = explode(",", $orderitems);
        $k = 0;
        $oDate = new DateTime($orderData['created_at']);
        $sDate = $oDate->format("M d, Y");

        while ($k < count($orderitemsarray))
            {

            if ($orderitemsarray[$k] != '0')
                {
                $stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details");
                $stmtorders->execute(array(":dorder_id" => $orderData['entity_id']));
                $roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $productdetail = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($orderitemsarray[$k]);
                $designerName = getDesignerName($productdetail->getDesignerID()) . " -(" . $productdetail->getDesignerID() . ")";
                $responce[] = array(
                    $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
                    $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
                    $orderitemsarray[$k],
                    $productdetail->getName() ,
                    $designerName,
                    $orderData['status'],
                    $orderData['grand_total'],
                    $orderData['customer_email'],
                    $commission,
                    $dorderStatus,              
                    $sDate
                );

                }

            $k++;
            $i++;
            }
        }

    echo json_encode($responce);
    }
```

**Edit** : Sales_flat_order table

[image]

**Edit 2**

Below code is reason for displaying both Designers Products, what code i need to use for displaying only that designer products

`$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id',array('like' => '%'.$_SESSION['userSession'].'%'));`

Comment: designer column represent the current user?

Comment: @QaisarSatti yes , in image if you see `kidsdial2` is owner of product `product1` &  `kidsdial3` is owner of product `product2`

Comment: what represent the  `kidsdial2 -(4)` in that `-(4)`

Comment: @QaisarSatti  `4` is `Designer  id` , we will enter that under `catalog > manage Products` section....

Comment: these are values of `tbl_users` table? what is column name for username?

Comment: @QaisarSatti yes these are values of `tbl_users` table. column name of "Designer" is `name`

Comment: which table you want to add the filter `sales_flat_orde`r or `order_detail`?

Comment: @QaisarSatti `order_details` table only.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento what return $rows['id'] and $_SESSION['userSession'] in your query?

Comment: @Rakesh when i tried this : `print $rows['id'];`, i got `Notice: Undefined variable: rows in `

Comment: which value return by $_SESSION['userSession']?

Comment: @Rakesh result : 4

Comment: @Rakesh when i tried printing $_SESSION['userSession'] with other email id, i got `3` , means its resulting `userID` of customer......

Comment: first diagram in above which table represent?

Comment: @Rakesh in 1st diagram from `order Id` to `Shipping` columns we are fetching from `sales_flat_order` table [magento db] & `paid status` column is giving static values. in 2nd diagram we added `custom columns` to `sales_flat_order` table.... i.e `designer_id` & `product_id`.....

Comment: I think you have to use finset condition instead of like in your sales/model collection, Using finset you have get proper result of your customer id

Comment: @Rakesh if you post an answer with code, that will be really helpfull for me.....

Comment: first, your collection is give correct result, for $order ?

Comment: @Rakesh i am getting this : `Notice: Undefined variable: order` but when i tried [this code](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphpfile.asp?filename=demo_db_select_oo) to fetch value from `order_details` table, i can able to display value present in DB in site.....

Comment: I have updated answer may be you have use ful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFter Long Discussion WE come to this conclusion

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id', array(
'like' => '%' . $_SESSION['userSession'] . '%'
))
->addAttributeToSelect('designer_id')
->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
->addAttributeToSelect('dproduct_id')
->addAttributeToSelect('customer_id')
->addAttributeToSelect('increment_id')
->addAttributeToSelect('updated_at')
->addAttributeToSelect('status')
->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
->addAttributeToSelect('state');
```

and In foreach Loop

```
foreach($order as $orderData)
{
$k = 0;
      $orderitems = $orderData['dproduct_id'];
      $orderitemsarray = explode(",", $orderitems);

        $oDate = new DateTime($orderData['created_at']);
        $sDate = $oDate->format("M d, Y");

        while ($k < count($orderitemsarray))
            {

            if ($orderitemsarray[$k] != '0')
                {
                $stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details");
                $stmtorders->execute(array(":dorder_id" => $orderData['entity_id']));
                $roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



                if($data['type']=="admin")continue;

                if($data['dpaid_status']=='P'){$dorderStatus='Paid';}
                if($data['dpaid_status']=='U'){$dorderStatus='Unpaid';}
                if($data['dpaid_status']=='R'){$dorderStatus='Returned';}
                if($data['dpaid_status']==''){$dpaid_status='';}

                if ($roworders[

                'dproduct_id'] == '')
                    {
                    $dorderStatus = "Unpaid";
                    }
                  else
                    {
                    $dorderStatus = $roworders['dpaid_status'];
                    }

                if ($roworders['dproduct_id'] == '')
                    {
                    $commission = "comm";
                    }
                  else
                    {
                    $commission = $roworders['commission'];
                    }

                $productdetail = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($orderitemsarray[$k]);
                $designer_id = $productdetail->getDesignerID() ;
                if($accountType == "admin"){
                    $designerName = getDesignerName($productdetail->getDesignerID()) . " -(" . $productdetail->getDesignerID() . ")";
                    $responce[] = array(
                        $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
                        $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
                        $orderitemsarray[$k],
                        $productdetail->getName() ,
                        $designerName,
                        $orderData['status'],
                        $orderData['grand_total'],
                        $orderData['customer_email'],
                        $commission,
                        $dorderStatus,             
                        $sDate
                    );

                }else{

                if( $designer_id== $_SESSION['userSession'] ){
                    $designerName = getDesignerName($productdetail->getDesignerID()) . " -(" . $productdetail->getDesignerID() . ")";
                    $responce[] = array(
                        $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
                        $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
                        $orderitemsarray[$k],
                        $productdetail->getName() ,
                        $designerName,
                        $orderData['status'],
                        $orderData['grand_total'],
                        $orderData['customer_email'],
                        $commission,
                        $dorderStatus,             
                        $sDate
                    );
                }
              }

            $k++;
            $i++;
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: stilll same result is displaying..... [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/orders2.php) , email : kidsdial2@gmail.com , pw : kidsdial2

Comment: @BabyinMagento still loading there is something problem with your url

Comment: sorry for that , please wait for some time or try in another window, it take some time, i will improve performance once i done with features....

Comment: @BabyinMagento please check my updated answer I have removed extra space

Comment: sorry, still same result.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento I am not able access your URL may be its my firewall issue I will check once I reach other place

Comment: @BabyinMagento your credentials not working

Comment: I checked it again, its working, okay please try one more time, once you login you can see this screen : http://prnt.sc/dhooa0

Comment: @BabyinMagento check updated answer

Comment: now its displaying only 2 rows , thats what i also wanted, means `designer1` have only 2 rows, but its not displaying any values, inside table..... can you see [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/orders2.php) , also `dates` are displaying today dates not correct dates as in [link5](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/orders.php)

Comment: got the point, now its not fetching  any values from `sales_flat_order_details` table..... please help for that.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento Please check updated one

Comment: sorry, again its displaying both designer products as in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/orders2.php)

Comment: @BabyinMagento let me check again from my side

Comment: @BabyinMagento please check updated one

Comment: still its displaying both designer produtcts.....

Comment: when i used [this solution](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148140/hide-designer-column-in-designer-dashboard) it displayed only 1 designer products but i faced issue of `product name & id` was not displaying, so i left that solution.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49956/discussion-between-murtuza-zabuawala-and-baby-in-magento).

Answer (score 2):

This will be your query

```
$designers= $rows['name'].' ('.$rows['id'].')';
$userbasedorder = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE Designer=:designer");
$userbasedorder->execute(array(":designer"=>$designers));
```

Comment: its not displaying any orders of `Designer` , i replaced your code by `else` part code : `$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id',array('like' => '%'.$_SESSION['userSession'].'%'));`

Comment: you said it is `order_details` table

Comment: check the value of `$designers= $rows['name'].' ('.$rows['id'].')';` it is correct or not?

Comment: sorry, we need to filter with help of `sales_flat_order` table , please check `Edit` part in question . `Designer id 4` is owner of `product id  15517`

Comment: The image is of  table of `sales_flat_order` or other?

Comment: yes, its image of `sales_flat_order` , we added custom columns :  `designer_id , dproduct_id` in that table

Comment: i don't see any column in that? `designer_id , dproduct_id` can you update the so i can see it?

Comment: you can see `Edit` part in question , also i uploaded column names here : http://prntscr.com/dco12b

Comment: use `->addFieldToFilter('designer_id', array('finset' => $_SESSION['userSession']));`

Comment: still its displaying both products of order....

Comment: value of this? $_SESSION['userSession'] is correct id of designer?

Comment: yes, that is correct id.....

Comment: then `finset` must work i used it many time it used for comma separated values check you code again

Comment: looks like code is fine,  is there any way i can debug to display results or some errors ?

Comment: you check ids by `print_r($order->getAllIds());`

Comment: when i  add that code in top, i got `Notice: Undefined variable: order in `   & `Fatal error: Call to a member function getAllIds() on a non-object `

Comment: not after the $order code then you get the result

Comment: i added  after the $order code , now `orders are not displaying` , you  can check [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/orders1.php) email : kidsdial2@gmail.com , pw : kidsdial2 , [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/orders1.php)

Comment: @BabyinMagento don't have time for that dear i can only provide code.. it still a messy thing

Answer (score 1):

You can get designer_id from **sales_flat_order** table using **`finset`** query condition to get correct result from comma separated value,

Replace your else part in query,

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id', array(
        'like' => '%' . $_SESSION['userSession'] . '%'));
```

With below one,

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();

$order->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id',array(  array('finset'=> array($_SESSION['userSession']) ) ) );
```

Comment: i tried your code, still if we login with 1st designer account, `designer2` products information are displaying....

Comment: [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/orders1.php) , email : kidsdial2@gmail.com , pw : kidsdial2

Comment: in $order not any data return for you?

Comment: i am getting this : `Notice: Undefined variable: order` when i used this : `print $order;`

Comment: I think you have to debug from first line of your code, first check $rows value is found or not?

Comment: getting error : `Notice: Undefined variable: rows in ` for `print $rows;` , but i can able to display all values of database in site page.....

Comment: then in order you cant display value of order data? Cause error are same in both case

Comment: if you can see db : http://prnt.sc/dicbex , i am displaying all values in site in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/orders1.php)

Comment: Yes in db value are display but You have to check for $order using only, $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection(); without filter session id and check order data is geting or not?

Comment: `Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in ` error when i used `$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
 print $order;`

Comment: you have to issue regarding to call mage.php file, require_once '../../app/Mage.php'; change its to require_once '../app/Mage.php';

Comment: whenever Mage.php is not called at that time, you doesnt get magento records because your entry file is not called perfect.

Comment: you can check link, http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8147/adding-magentos-required-structure-to-a-php-file or http://www.seanbreeden.com/run-magento-code-from-an-external-php-file/

Comment: when i used this code : `print $order;` at the `end of file` i got error : `Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in`,  when i used this code `print $order;` after this line `$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();` its not displaying any error....

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the way you're saving the Designer ids, there are 4 ways a designer id can be saved, so you just need to add all those in your condition.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter(
    array('designer_id', 'like' => $_SESSION['userSession'] . ',%'), // When the designer id appears at the first
    array('designer_id', 'like' => '%,' . $_SESSION['userSession'] . ',%'), // when the designer id appears in the middle
    array('designer_id', 'like' => '%,' . $_SESSION['userSession']), // when the designer id appears at last
    array('designer_id', 'eq' => $_SESSION['userSession']) // when that is the only designer id
)
```

The above code applies `OR` condition to the filter conditions according to [this reference.](http://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/Using+Magento+1.x+collections) (Search for Filter Condition Codes and you can find the code after condition table.

If the above doesn't work, try to replace `addAttributeToFilter` with `addFieldToFilter` as suggested by @Murtuza

Comment: let me check now.....

Comment: Hope it helps...

Comment: I can see the table when I log in

Comment: Can we continue this in chat (http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=magento.stackexchange.com)?