# Hide Designer Column in Designer Dashboard

Tags: magento-1.9

we are displaying all the order related information in custom page : **www.1234.com/php/site6/orders.php**

if we login than we can see all orders. Here Order id, Prodcut Ids..etc are fetching from magento database.

[image]

but only **Designer** column is fething from custom database [ table : `tbl_users` , column: `name` ]

[image]

There are 2 types of dashboard - admin & designer, if designer login than we want to **hide column** `Designer`

**php**

```
function getDesignerCollection()

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ":uid" => $designerId
    ));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $row['name'];
    }

    {
    $accountType = $rows['type'];
    if ($accountType == "admin")
        {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id', array(
            'nin' => '0'
        ));     
        }
      else
        {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id', array(
            'like' => '%' . $_SESSION['userSession'] . '%'
        ));     
        }

    $i = 0;
    foreach($order as $orderData)
        {
        $orderitems = $orderData['dproduct_id'];
        $orderitemsarray = explode(",", $orderitems);
        $k = 0;
        $oDate = new DateTime($orderData['created_at']);
        $sDate = $oDate->format("Y-m-d");
        while ($k < count($orderitemsarray))
            {
            if ($orderitemsarray[$k] != '0')
                {
                $stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE designerorder_id=:designerorder_id");
                $stmtorders->execute(array(
                    ":designerorder_id" => $orderData['entity_id']
                ));
                $roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $productdetail = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($orderitemsarray[$k]);
                $designerName = getDesignerName($productdetail->getDesignerID()) . " -(" . $productdetail->getDesignerID() . ")";
                $responce[] = array(
                    $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
                    $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
                    $orderitemsarray[$k],
                    $productdetail->getName() ,
                    $designerName,
                    $orderData['status'],
                    $orderData['grand_total'],
                    $orderData['customer_email'],
                    $commission,
                    $dorderStatus,
                    $sDate
                );
                }

            $k++;
            $i++;
            }
        }

    echo json_encode($responce);
    }
```

**script**

```
var dsOption= {
    fields :[   
        {name : 'entity_id'  }, 
        {name : 'entity_id'  },
        {name : 'product_id'  },
        {name : 'product_name'},
        {name : 'designer_id'  },       
        {name : 'status'  },        
        {name : 'grand_total'  },
        {name : 'customer_email'  },
        {name : 'commission'  },    
        {name : 'paid_status'  },       
        {name : 'created_at'},                  
    ],
    recordType : 'array',
    data : __TEST_DATA__
}   

var colsOption = [  
    {id: 'entity_id' , header: "Order Id" , width :"15",renderer : my_renderId},   
    {id: 'created_at' , header: "Order Date" , width :"120"},
    {id: 'entity_id' , header: "Order Id" , width :"75"},
    {id: 'product_id' , header: "Product Id" , width :"70"},
    {id: 'product_name' , header: "Product Name" , width :"200"},
    {id: 'designer_id' , header: "Designer" , width :"110"},
    {id: 'status' , header: "Order Status" , width :"100"},  
    {id: 'grand_total' , header: " Order Amount" , width :"120"},
    {id: 'customer_email' , header: "User Email" , width :"150"},     
    {id: 'paid_status' , header: "Paid status" , width :"80"},
    {id: 'commission' , header: "commission" , width :"80"}

];
```

If i remove below line from above script, than "Designer" column will hide in both admin & Designer dashboard.

```
{id: 'designer_id' , header: "Designer" , width :"110"},
```

Comment: This is a PHP only question. Even though it's linked to a Magento database it does not involve Magento code thus I suggest you ask it on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism Thanks for your comment, when i asked same questions in stackoverflow, they suggested me to ask here as because the question involves code like `$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id', array(
            'like' => '%' . $_SESSION['userSession'] . '%'
        ));     ` , so i asked here, i will take your suggestion & try to ask in stackoverflow if the question is purely related to php....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change below code:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id', array(
            'like' => '%' . $_SESSION['userSession'] . '%'
        ));
```

To:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id', array(
            'like' => '%' . $_SESSION['userSession'] . '%'
        ))
->addAttributeToSelect('created_at') 
->addAttributeToSelect('customer_id') 
->addAttributeToSelect('increment_id') 
->addAttributeToSelect('updated_at') 
->addAttributeToSelect('status') 
->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
->addAttributeToSelect('state');
```

Add your field which you need to show for designer collection

Comment: yes `designer` names are hiding, but I want to hide complete column http://prnt.sc/ddij3b , also  `product_id` & `product_names` are also hiding, i used this code to display those, but still its not displaying  , code :  `->addAttributeToSelect('product_id')`  & `->addAttributeToSelect('product_name')`

Comment: please check product name and product id in your collection or not

Comment: when i used this code : `->addAttributeToSelect('dproduct_id')` product id , product name will display, but `designer names` will also display....

Comment: all other columns information are fetching from `sales_flat_order` table, but there is no `product_id` & `product_name` columns in `sales_flat_order` table , is that is the reason ?

Comment: Yes may be that would be reason

Comment: okay, is there any way to display those `product name` in designer dashboard as `product_name` is displaying in admin dashboard ?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this from the CSS also.

for this you have to add a css class "designer" in all column of designer including header of designer tab.

In Head section call a block file where you can check the user type and on the basis of that you can add a css of "designer" class with `display:none`.

Comment: can you please give me an example for how i can add `css class` for atleast one column . is there any way we can add css for below javscript line :
`var colsOption = [ 
{id: 'entity_id' , header: "Order Id" , width :"15",renderer : my_renderId}, 
];`

Comment: @BabyinMagento you can add css for id 'designer_id' in your case.

Comment: i tried this : `<style>

#designer_id { disply : none; }

</style>` , can you please tell what i need to do for  `In Head section call a block file where you can check the user type and on the basis of that you can add a css of "designer" class with display:none.`

Comment: can you please tell what else i need to do after line : `<style> #designer_id { disply : none; } </style>`

Comment: @BabyinMagento You can add this css inside `if ($accountType != "admin")` code in top of the page

Comment: i tried `<?php

if ($accountType != "admin")
{
?>
 
 <style> #designer_id { display : none; } </style>

<?php 
}` , i got error : `Notice: Undefined variable: accountType`  is this correct way ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento You have to get the value of  $accountType variable first as same you are getting this value in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49591/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-ashish-jagnani).

Answer (score 0):

```
var colsOption = [
    {id: 'entity_id' , header: "Order Id" , width :"15",renderer : my_renderId},
    {id: 'created_at' , header: "Order Date" , width :"120"},
    {id: 'entity_id' , header: "Order Id" , width :"75"},
    {id: 'product_id' , header: "Product Id" , width :"70"},
    {id: 'product_name' , header: "Product Name" , width :"200"},
<?php if ($is_admin) echo "{id: 'designer_id' , header: 'Designer' , width :'110'},"; ?>
    {id: 'status' , header: "Order Status" , width :"100"},
    {id: 'grand_total' , header: " Order Amount" , width :"120"},
    {id: 'customer_email' , header: "User Email" , width :"150"},
    {id: 'dpaid_status' , header: "Paid status" , width :"80"},
    {id: 'commission' , header: "commission" , width :"80"}

];
```