# Display Product Id & Name of Order in custom page

Tags: magento-1.9, product

we are displaying all the order related information in custom page : **www.1234.com/php/site6/orders.php**

if we login as admin , than we can see all order informations.

[image]

if we login as Designer ,

1) **Product name & Product Id are not displaying**. but i want to display

[image]

Here Order id, Order Date are fetching from **"sales_flat_order"** table.

Product Id, Product name are fetching from **"sales_flat_order_item"** table

but only **Designer** column is fetching from custom database [ table : `tbl_users` , column: `name` ]

```
function getDesignerCollection()
    {
    $user_home = new USER();
    require_once '../../app/Mage.php';

    Mage::app();
    $stmts = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
    $stmts->execute(array(
        ":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']
    ));
    $rows = $stmts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $accountType = $rows['type'];
    if ($accountType == "admin")
        {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id', array(
            'nin' => '0'
        ));     
        }
      else
        {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id', array(
            'like' => '%' . $_SESSION['userSession'] . '%'
        ))
                ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at') 
                ->addAttributeToSelect('increment_id')  // order id
                ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('grand_total') 
                ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_email')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('state');        
        }

    $i = 0;
    foreach($order as $orderData)
        {
        $orderitems = $orderData['dproduct_id'];
        $orderitemsarray = explode(",", $orderitems);
        $k = 0;
        $oDate = new DateTime($orderData['created_at']);
        $sDate = $oDate->format("Y-m-d");
        while ($k < count($orderitemsarray))
            {
            if ($orderitemsarray[$k] != '0')
                {
                $stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE designerorder_id=:designerorder_id");
                $stmtorders->execute(array(
                    ":designerorder_id" => $orderData['entity_id']
                ));
                $roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $productdetail = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($orderitemsarray[$k]);
                $designerName = getDesignerName($productdetail->getDesignerID()) . " -(" . $productdetail->getDesignerID() . ")";
                $responce[] = array(
                    $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
                    $orderData->getIncrementId() ,
                    $orderitemsarray[$k],
                    $productdetail->getName() ,
                    $designerName,
                    $orderData['status'],
                    $orderData['grand_total'],
                    $orderData['customer_email'],
                    $commission,
                    $dorderStatus,
                    $sDate
                );
                }

            $k++;
            $i++;
            }
        }

    echo json_encode($responce);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not getting any thing on this line:

`$productdetail = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($orderitemsarray[$k]);`

Please make sure that you are getting the data in `$orderitemsarray`, as I think you have to get the product object in that. But it is not getting that object anyhow so you are not getting the product details, as a result product id, name and designer details are not displayed correctly.

Comment: Before `product_id , product name, designer id` all were displaying, I don't want to display `Designer_id`, so i followed [this link answer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148140/hide-designer-column-in-designer-dashboard) , but now i want to display `product id & name`. if i use this code : `->addAttributeToSelect('dproduct_id')`, than `product id, name` will display. but along with that it will display `designer id` also , i don't want that.

Comment: can you please update the answer with code to get results of `product id & name`

Comment: If you are getting the `product id, name & designer id` in 
`->addAttributeToSelect('dproduct_id')` as array, than you can unset the designer id from it.

Like From your code you are getting that details in `$orderitems = $orderData['dproduct_id'];` So if the result you are getting as an array than you can unset that from the variable `$orderitems`

I am not writing the code as I dont have the exact idea in which form you are getting the details of product id,name and designer id.

Comment: can you please tell what code i  need to use to unset the designer id as array.....

Comment: you can do it by using `unset($orderitems['designer_id'])`. You can use the key for designer id you are getting in that array in place of designer_id.

Comment: i tried this code : `unset($orderitems['designer_id']);` after line `->addAttributeToSelect('state');   `  but still its displaying `designer_id`